# Most efficient way to remove duplicates from Python list while preserving order and removing the oldest element

Tags: python, list

I've seen a bunch of solutions on the site to remove duplicates while preserving the oldest element.  I'm interested in the opposite: removing duplicates while preserving the newest element, for example:

```
list = ['1234','2345','3456','1234']
list.append('1234')
>>> ['1234','2345','3456','1234','1234']
list = unique(list)
>>> ['2345','3456','1234']
```

How would something like this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to reverse the list with `reversed()`, then do it like described elsewhere and then reverse it again.

Comment: Well, you could reverse the list, do what the other answers said, and reverse it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requires the items (or keys) to be hashable, works in-place on list-likes:

```
def inplace_unique_latest(L, key=None):
  if key is None:
    def key(x):
      return x
  seen = set()
  n = iter(xrange(len(L) - 1, -2, -1))
  for x in xrange(len(L) - 1, -1, -1):
    item = L[x]
    k = key(item)
    if k not in seen:
      seen.add(k)
      L[next(n)] = item
  L[:next(n) + 1] = []
```

Comment: I may be reading it wrong, but won't `seen[x]` be wrong once you've popped from the list? You'll end up popping the wrong item because everything has shifted?