# How to ensure unique values in a multidimensional array?

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
color_names = ('red', 'blue', 'orange', 'red')
```

From the list above i want to do something like this:

```
colors = [(0, 'red'), (1, 'blue'), (2, 'orange')]
```

Every color should be unique, thats why i have to ignore the second 'red' in the first list.
My current solution has to many loops and conditions. I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Does order matter? If so, which element is picked?

Comment: Would you be better off using a dictionary, with colour as the key? so colors = { 'red':0, 'blue':1, 'orange':2 }? Otherwise you would have to implement the test manually

Comment: Why does your title say "multidimensional array" when this list is only 1D?

Comment: Order doesn't matter. I need this format for a ChoiceField in django.

Comment: the second list has lists in it. The title is focused on the result wich i am looking for

Comment: Those are tuples, not lists, but I understand (calling it `list of tuples` might have been clearer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you said that order doesn't matter, you can simply do:

```
list(enumerate(set(color_names)))
```

Comment: Make it a real list and it will be perfect.

Comment: @vkuzma - `set` makes the colors unique: `set(['red', 'blue', 'red'])` results into a set with two different elements.

Comment: What is if order matters? Is there any way to accomplish this easely?

Comment: @vkuzma: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000621/most-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicates-from-python-list-while-preserving-order)

Answer (score 3):

If order does not matter:

```
color_names = ('red', 'blue', 'orange', 'red')
colors = [(i, color) for i, color in enumerate(set(color_names))]
```

Or:

```
colors = list(enumerate(set(color_names)))
```

[`set()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) makes the list contain unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

Too wordy but it works:

```
color_names = ('red', 'blue', 'orange', 'red')
i = 0
res = []
for item in set(color_names):
    res.append((i,item))
    i+=1

print res
```

Comment: If you are iterating over a `set`, you don't need to check that the element is not already in `res`. Plus, `in` does not work the way you think it does. Try this: `>>> 'blue' in [(0, 'blue')]
False`